# slow lagging and not responding windows 10 and visual studio

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am having a serious problem with my OS which is lagging and not responding I can't give it more than some tasks a time and lags all of a sudden I'm using only the browser most of the times what's wrong ?

also same problem with visual studio it's so slow opening up and closing it but after that works smoothly though it can crash if I clicked a lot here and there

I am working on a laptop: OS windows 10 64bit, intel core i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80 (1.99), RAM 8GB, GPU Radeon 520, intel UHD Graphics 620 memory 2048mb

I am going to buy an SSD and a RAM soon also reinstall the windows 10 but I want to know if I can fix it before all this and what's wrong exactly why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- putting my pc on adjust for best performance from adjust the
  appearance and performance for windows or performance options
- updating windows didn't help much but it should
- press Windows logo key + R and type services.msc and press enter key. Here look for Sysmain, right-click on it and choose Stop.
- press windows logo key + R and then type %temp% and hit enter. after that please press ctrl + A and then after press shift + delete
- press windows logo key + R and then type temp and hit enter. after that please press ctrl + A and then after press shift + delete
- press windows logo key + R and then type prefetch and hit enter. after that please press ctrl + A and then after press shift + delete
- for doing clean boot ..., follow these below steps.

  - Press the "Windows + R" key to open a Run box.
  - Type msconfig and click OK.
  - On the General tab, click Selective startup.
  - Clear the Load startup items checkbox.
  - Click the Services tab.
  - Select the Hide all Microsoft services checkbox (at the bottom).
  - Click Disable all.
  - Click the Startup tab.
  - Click Open Task Manager.
  - On the Startup tab, right-click each enabled startup item and select Disable.
  - Restart your system.

if you want to see your system information, press windows logo key + R and type msinfo32 and press enter key.

it is better to do that in safe mood go to recovery options from settings or search change advanced startup options